# How to move batch file without di

Tags: file, batch-file, move, direction

How do i create a batch that will move it self to another direction independent of what direction it is in? To do it less confusing i have made an example:

Example.bat

```
@echo off
Xcopy /y /-y /c "example[.bat]" "c:\users\%username%\desktop\hallo im here"
Echo done! 
Pause >nul
```

I know that it would normaly look like this:

```
Xcopy "c:\anyfolder\Example.bat" "c:\users\%username%\desktop\hallo im here"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
cd /d "c:\anyfolder"
Xcopy /y "c:\users\%username%\desktop\hallo im here\example.bat"
```

and also:

```
cd /d "c:\anyfolder"
Xcopy /y "%~f0"
```

Comment: Thanks! It helped a lot!  And btw i played around with %~f0, and found this: start %~f0 (new line) taskkill /f -im cmd.exe  (new line) pause :-)

Answer (score 1):

To move the running batch file to another folder:

```
move /y "c:\anyfolder\%~f0" "c:\users\%username%\desktop\"
```

But it will generate an error when the command is executed and the batch file will stop running.

Comment: So %~f0 means the running batch file /me (the batch file) = i will go to this folder! :-)